# How to use sqlite db functions to set values from calculation

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have an app (its ruby on rails but it shouldn't matter) where I am bulk loading items and quantities per branch.

The database is sqlite.

Say I have a two tables: items and quantities.

```
items columns:
 id
 quantity

quantities columns:
 id
 item_id
 branch_id
 value
```

I need to be able to loop through all records in the items table set the item.quantity to the sum of all quantity.value where item_id matches item.id

I would like to know if there is a way to do this all within a sql query (the select and update) so that I don't have to pull the data out of the database, do the calculation and then write the updated quantity back to each item, instead I would like to have it all occur in the database using sql statements and functions.

Is this possible in a sql query function db side?

```
example:
item[1] = {id=>1,quantity=>0}
quantity[1] = {id=>1,item_id=>1,value=>100,branch_id=>1}
quantity[2] = {id=>2,item_id=>1,value=>200,branch_id=>2}
quantity[3] = {id=>3,item_id=>1,value=>300,branch_id=>3}

item[1].quantity = quantity[1].value + quantity[2].value + quantity[3].value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an `update` query.  In this case, you can use a correlated subquery to calculate the sum of the quantities for a given item:

```
update item
    set quantity = (select sum(value) from quantities where item.id = quantities.item_id);
```

EDIT:

If you want to speed it up putting an index on `quantities(item_id, value)`.

You could also summarize `quantities` in a temporary table and use this instead.  The index, however, however, should be sufficient for performance.

Comment: Fantastic! - I had to tweak it slightly for the correct table name and field names to this: "update items set quantity = (select sum(value) from quantities where items.id = quantities.item_id);" I have nearly 100k items and 500k quantities in the db so it will take a very long time, longer than bulk loading in the first place really... Is there a way to optimize / speed up even further using pragma statements or something similar? I would likely limit execution to item_ids that were just updated but I was thinking that a way to do ensure all items are correct would be good.

Comment: BTW, here is the final ruby on rails active record based statement I am using now with your help and limiting the items I update to an array of item_ids -> Item.update_all("quantity = (select sum(value) from quantities where items.id = quantities.item_id)",["id IN (?)",item_ids]) ... works great! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating your data! Which means you must always keeping everything in sync.
I would prefer to create a view and get total quantities from there:

```
CREATE TABLE items(id, ...);
CREATE TABLE quantities(id, item_id, branch_id, value, ...);
CREATE VIEW items_sum AS SELECT items.*, SUM(quantities.value) AS quantity FROM items LEFT JOIN quantities ON items.id=quantities.item_id GROUP BY items.id;
```

As `items_sum` is a query, you don't have to update it. `SELECT * FROM items_sum;`will return desired results for total quantities.